# Track when application is uninstalled on iOS

Tags: ios, uninstallation

i have been trying to find a way to track when our app is uninstalled from iOS device :

1. Sending Push notification, this sometimes gives the desired 410 ( app uninstalled ) most of the time returns just 200. I could not find any examples on how to use their Feedback service, which seems obsolite.
2. Background pinging works only when the app is in the background but not shutdown. It probably could work if the app uses location services, but that would require more permissions.

Is there any way stable way to track this at all ?

many thanks

Comment: Why do you care whether the app was removed vs. installed but no longer used, or on a phone that's lost or retired? Seems like it'd be better and easier to invert the logic and keep track of the users who actively use your app. Also: why is this tagged `churn` -- it doesn't appear to have anything to do with code churn, which is what that tag is for.

Comment: I guess re-engagement ?

Comment: Removing an app from a particular device doesn't mean that the user isn't engaged – they might be using your app on a different device. Conversely, keeping your app doesn't mean that they're engaged.

Answer (score 0):

You can share your exact case to get alternative solutions.

BTW, The nearest technique to achieve this is:

1- Send silent notification, Check the following:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app
And Note the following:

> The system treats background notifications as low-priority: you can
>   use them to refresh your app’s content, but the system doesn’t
>   guarantee their delivery.

2- Once you have received the notification in the device, call a web-service to flag this device/ user.

---

In case you want this for collecting insights, you can use analytical frameworks like: Google Analytics to get all insights that you want (Active, Downloaded, ...). Check the following:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3

Comment: Hi Amr, i have a app with background notification but it does not update when the app is killed, is the notification handler going to execute if the app is killed ?

Comment: I the case of the user killed the App. The notification handler most probably doesn't execute. That is a reflection to: The system treats background notifications as low-priority.
,So you may need and additional work around as: You need to handle to call this service on the App launch also, then put a number of days threshold in your server to consider the user that exceeded this number as an uninstalled one.